# Resizing Image stream with ImageResizer

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I am trying to resize an image from stream in the code below and get the output stream without saving a file.

```
Instructions instructions = new Instructions ()
{
    Width   = width,
    Height  = height,
    Mode    = FitMode.Max,
    Format  = null
};

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream ();
ImageJob imageJob = new ImageJob (inStream, memoryStream, instructions);
imageJob.Build ();
```

However, the moment the code reaches imageJob.Build() an exception will be thrown.

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

I am not sure if I am missing any packages in my setup for this to happen, or I am not supposed to use ImageJob in this manner. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you see that version of the assembly in your project references?

Comment: I do not see it anywhere. Looking through the build output I noticed this warning message.
"warning NU1701: Package 'ImageResizer 4.2.5' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."

Perhaps this is the reason...

Comment: It does not change even when I linked my .NET Standard 2.0 class library with a new .NET Framework 4.6.1 class library containing imageresizer package

Comment: I think that might be your issue: There isn't a ImageResizer NuGet package for .NET standard projects.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net Core the ImageResizer nuget package will not be compatible. Instead use

https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet-server

or just use System.Drawing and the GetThumbnailImage from the Image class

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: GetThumbnailImage uses the embedded EXIF thumbnail which is usually of extremely low quality.